# comparison of unsigned type with signed type

Tags: c

My compiler (DSP SHARC) is very picky. When I build with remarks I get this error:

```
[cc1123] foo.c:1511 {D} remark: comparison of unsigned type
          with signed type
      while (taille > 0)
```

Two solutions:

1. The compiler is right and I should write

   ```c
   size_t taille;
   ...
   while(taille > (size_t)0)
   ```
2. The compiler is stupid and I should ignore this remark
3. Another solution that may involve ISO or MISRA standards

What should I do with this remark?

**EDIT**

Actually I might better write this example like

```c
 while(taille) {...}
```

But, this is not related to my initial question

Comment: The compiler might be stupid, but ignoring warnings could hide some bug somewhere else. There is actually a problem, because `taille > 0` will always be true. Either declare `taille` as `int taille;` or change the condition to `while (taille != 0)`.

Comment: This seems a bit overzealous of the compiler, but you should be able to use `0u` to make it happy.

Comment: @coin exactly, thats why the right condition is `while (taille != 0)`. But you should be aware of `size_t value = 0` and `value--` is defined and it will wrap around bits, so it's value is `UINT_MAX`.

Comment: @Wintermute I don't think it will be happy that way, I thought of it too, but `size_t x;` then `x > 0` always, what is not always true is `x == 0`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Unsigned doesn't mean greater than zero!

Comment: I don't understand your point. if `taille = 0`, the condition `taille > 0` is false while `taille >= 0` is always true. Am I wrong?

Comment: `x > 0` is not true if `x == 0`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh what if talie is 0?

Comment: Sorry somehow I missed that. Deleting commemt now.

Comment: Suggest `while (taille > 0u)`.

Comment: @iharob The comment "because `taille > 0` will always be true." is certainly incorrect.  When `taille` has the value `0`, it is not true.

Comment: @chux you're right i meant `taille >= 0` is always true.

Comment: @iharob Agree `taille >= 0` is a problem when `tailie` is some unsigned number, but `taille >= 0` is not the issue as OP's code is `taille > 0`.

Comment: @chux I deleted my answer because i realized that the compiler is complaining unecessarily about `while (taille > 0)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMO, the compiler is weak or at least pedantic. To quiet this unneeded warning, use:

```
while (taille > 0u)
```

---

BTW: Love the "Two solutions: 1. 2. *and* 3."

---

Late credit: Now see [@Wintermute](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4301306/wintermute) commented similarly on this earlier than myself.